# Can't build bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind

When I starting `make` I always get the same error. I think maybe it's have anything to do with Berkeley DB, but I'm not sure. I followed in this guide - https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md#berkeley-db

```
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/insaf/bitcoin/src'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/insaf/bitcoin/src'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/insaf/bitcoin'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/insaf/bitcoin'
  CXXLD    bitcoind
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldb_cxx-4.8
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:5953: bitcoind] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/insaf/bitcoin/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:16272: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/insaf/bitcoin/src'
make: *** [Makefile:825: all-recursive] Error 1
```

output, when I type `./configure`
configure: WARNING: LRELEASE not found; bitcoin-qt frontend will not be built
checking whether to build Bitcoin Core GUI... no
checking for Berkeley DB C++ headers... default
configure: error: Found Berkeley DB other than 4.8, required for portable BDB wallets (--with-incompatible-bdb to ignore or --without-bdb to disable BDB wallet support)

And yeah, I searched how I can install ldb_cxx, but I don't find it.
When I launch ./install_db64.sh it gives next output:

```
db4 build complete.
  When compiling bitcoind, run `./configure` in the following way:
  export BDB_PREFIX='<PATH-TO>/db4'
  ./configure BDB_LIBS="-L${BDB_PREFIX}/lib -ldb_cxx-4.8" BDB_CFLAGS="-I${BDB_PREFIX}/include" ...
```

And I also did `sudo pacman -S git base-devel`
And it:

```
./autogen.sh export BDB_PREFIX='/home/insaf/bitcoin/db4'                                                         ✔  5s  
  ./configure BDB_LIBS="-L${BDB_PREFIX}/lib -ldb_cxx-4.8" BDB_CFLAGS="-I${BDB_PREFIX}/include"
```

Comment: Did you install `libdb_cxx-4.8` and how? If you built it from source with `make install`, it's likely in `/usr/local/lib` instead of system-wide folder and that may require additional configuration.

Comment: Apparently the `install_db4.sh` script gives you some guidance on how to invoke `configure`. Did you do so? Please edit your question with the arguments and output of the most recent `./configure` invocation.

Comment: I edit my question, I hope it's help you to help me xD

Comment: The user below has solved the problem, you did not set the BDB_PREFIX variable properly, once you do your system will link the proper ldb.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while building `bitcoind` using this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@meeDamian/bitcoin-full-node-on-rbp3-revised-88bb7c8ef1d1). It was because I forgot to run `export BDB_PREFIX=$(pwd)/db4` before the `./configure ...` and the `make`.

Comment: This is literally the correct answer, anyone voting down on it has not a clue what they are on about.